# How can I insert value in a extra column in the relationship table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider these as my table structure

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

My `Appointments` table has an extra column called `relationship`. Everytime when i associate the Physician and the patient, I would like to add a relationship [my example sounds weird at so many levels] , how can i insert value into that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
patient = Patient.create(:name => 'Humpty Dumpty')
physician = Physician.create(:name => "All the King's horses and all the King's men")
appointment = Appointment.create(:patient => patient, :physician => physician, :relationship => 'surgeon')
```

Comment: Can you show what you have? Of course the above code will give an error, it was just an example. You have to adapt it to what you have, but you haven't shown what you have.

Comment: I created appropriate objects. If I take the sample above, I was able to create patient and physician objects but when I tried to create appointments i got an error saying `relationship cannot be null` irrespective of the fact that I gave `:relationship => 'General'` while creating my appointment object.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to say. This works for me in a sample I put together.